# SWIFT iOS9 create thumbnailImageData to Contacts

Tags: ios9, contacts

I'm using CNMutableContact to create a contact.
I can add image to contact with contact.imageData but there is also a thumbnail but it's a read-only data...

The thing is that without the thumbnail, the contact image doesn't appear during calls.

I have seen also imageDataAvailable option but it is set to true after the contact creation.

If someone knows how to set the thumbnail :)

Thank you!

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
contact.givenName = "Test Name"
let img = UIImage(named: "bg")
let data: NSData = NSData(data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img!)!)
contact.imageData = data

let storeEx = CNContactStore()
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
saveRequest.addContact(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil)
try! storeEx.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
```

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: iOS11 / Swift - general misbehavior still seems to happen, I see it on my devices and in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Seems specific to iOS9. It works on iOS10.

In the meanwhile, you can generate your own thumbnail data for iOS9 users by falling back to the full image when the thumbnail image is not available.

```
if (contact.thumbnailImageData) {
    _image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.thumbnailImageData];
} else if (contact.imageData) {
    // on iOS9, programmatically assigned imageData does not propogate to thumbnailImageData
    // Depending on your use case, you may want to resize and cache here.
    _image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
}
```